# I am currently trying to use the longitude and latitude to find zip codes. But i keep getting this error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'

Tags: python

```
gis = GIS("http://www.arcgis.com", "username", "password"

def get_zip(df, lon_field, lat_field):
    location = reverse_geocode((Geometry({"x":float(df[lon_field]), "y":float(df[lat_field]), "spatialReference":{"wkid": 4326}})))
    return location['address']['Postal']

#starting zipcode 
df_startzip = pd.DataFrame({
    'Lat': bike["start station latitude"].tolist(),
    'Lon': bike["start station longitude"].tolist()
})
start_zipcodes = df_startzip.apply(get_zip, axis=1, lat_field='Lat', lon_field='Lon')
```

when i run this on a small dataset with 100 or even 500 lines it works but when i increase it to a bigger dataset with 10000 it gives me the error "Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)'. I thought it may have something to do with missing values but to my knowledge there are no null values.

This is the error i have googled it and i still really don't understand what it means or how to fix it

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-d1fc4baf9d57> in <module>
      4     'Lon': bike["start station longitude"].tolist()
      5 })
----> 6 start_zipcodes = df_startzip.apply(get_zip, axis=1, lat_field='Lat', lon_field='Lon')

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7766             kwds=kwds,
   7767         )
-> 7768         return op.get_result()
   7769 
   7770     def applymap(self, func, na_action: Optional[str] = None) -> DataFrame:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    183             return self.apply_raw()
    184 
--> 185         return self.apply_standard()
    186 
    187     def apply_empty_result(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    274 
    275     def apply_standard(self):
--> 276         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    277 
    278         # wrap results

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    288             for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    289                 # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 290                 results[i] = self.f(v)
    291                 if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    292                     # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in f(x)
    108 
    109             def f(x):
--> 110                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
    111 
    112         else:

<ipython-input-113-2e0fbc6e52a1> in get_zip(df, lon_field, lat_field)
      1 def get_zip(df, lon_field, lat_field):
----> 2     location = reverse_geocode((Geometry({"x":float(df[lon_field]), "y":float(df[lat_field]), "spatialReference":{"wkid": 4326}})))
      3     return location['address']['Postal']

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcgis/geocoding/_functions.py in reverse_geocode(location, distance, out_sr, lang_code, return_intersection, for_storage, geocoder, feature_types, roof_top)
   1199         geocoder = arcgis.env.active_gis._tools.geocoders[0]
   1200         assert isinstance(geocoder, Geocoder)
-> 1201     return geocoder._reverse_geocode(location=location,
   1202                                      distance=distance,
   1203                                      out_sr=out_sr,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcgis/geocoding/_functions.py in _reverse_geocode(self, location, distance, out_sr, lang_code, return_intersection, for_storage, as_featureset, feature_types, location_type)
    291             params['locationType'] = location_type
    292 
--> 293         resp = self._con.post(url, params, token=self._token)
    294         if resp is not None and as_featureset:
    295             geom = copy.copy(resp['location'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcgis/gis/_impl/_con/_connection.py in post(self, path, params, files, **kwargs)
    714                 'An unknown error occurred: %s' % traceback.format_exc())
    715 
--> 716         return self._handle_response(resp=resp,
    717                                      out_path=out_path,
    718                                      file_name=file_name,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/arcgis/gis/_impl/_con/_connection.py in _handle_response(self, resp, file_name, out_path, try_json, force_bytes)
    502                     raise Exception(data['error'])
    503             else:
--> 504                 data = resp.json()
    505             #if 'error' in data:
    506                 #raise Exception(data['error'])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
    898                     # used.
    899                     pass
--> 900         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    901 
    902     @property

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    355             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    356             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 357         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    358     if cls is None:
    359         cls = JSONDecoder

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: The error is in the JSON being returned from arcgis.com. Perhaps you are exceeding a rate limit and an error message is being returned instead of a valid JSON response.

Comment: is there anyway to increase there rate limit?

Comment: I don't know for certain that is what is causing the problem, it's just a guess. Their web site might have some information. You can try doing 500 requests then pausing for a minute and doing the next 500 requests and see if that helps. Typically, web site charge a fee to get a higher rate limit, but I don't know about that one.